# python can't use base abstract calass property from subclass gettig AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, oop

i dont understand  here something that is basic 
how can i use property from base which is also abstract class from its sub class 
here is small code :

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
class Base(ABC):

    @property
    def is_ver0(self):
        return None

    @abstractmethod
    def execute_sql(self):
        print("Base execute_sql")

    def print_and_exit(self):
        print("Base")
```

And here is the sub class which implemanting the execute_sql and also want to set and get value of 
the base is_ver0
Although i can call super().print_and_exit with no problem i can call super().is_ver0
why ?

```
from base import Base
class Sub(Base):
   def __init__(self):
        self.execute_sql()
    def execute_sql(self):
        print("Sub execute_sql")
        super().print_and_exit
        super().is_ver0 = 1
        q = super().is_ver0
        print(q)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Sub()
    s.execute_sql()
```

but im getting this error :

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Dev/python/new_tester/sub.py", line 22, in <module>
    s = Sub()
  File "C:/Dev/python/new_tester/sub.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.execute_sql()
  File "C:/Dev/python/new_tester/sub.py", line 16, in execute_sql
    super().is_ver0 = 1
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'is_ver0'
```

**UPDATE**  still error
i added setter in to base class and still i got error
what basic thing i miss here ?

```
class Base(ABC):
    __xx = None
    @property
    def is_ver0(self):
        return self.__xx

    @__xx.setter
    def set_x(self,xxx):
        self.__xx = xxx

    @abstractmethod
    def execute_sql(self):
        print("Base execute_sql")

    def print_and_exit(self):
        print("Base")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Dev\python\new_tester\base.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Base(ABC):
  File "C:\Dev\python\new_tester\base.py", line 8, in Base
    @__xx.setter
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setter'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the attribute via `self.is_ver0 = 1`. However at the moment `Base` only defines a `property` without setter, so you need to include a method decorated with `@is_ver0.setter` that handles the corresponding logic.

Comment: @user63898 What do you mean?